AppLauncher can't find iOS version 18.0.1 disk image, xcode directly works ok though
I'm trying to launch my app using robovm on a connected device, using this gradle command:
./gradlew launchIOSDevice

I get this error:
AppLauncher failed with an exception:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No DeveloperDiskImage.dmg found in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport for iOS version 18.0.1
        at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.DeveloperImageResolver.findDeveloperImage(DeveloperImageResolver.java:117)
        at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.mountDeveloperImageIfRequired(AppLauncher.java:631)
        at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.launchInternal(AppLauncher.java:689)
        at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.launch(AppLauncher.java:1153)
        at org.robovm.compiler.target.ios.AppLauncherProcess$1.run(AppLauncherProcess.java:67)

If I open the path mentioned above, I only have folders going up to 16.4. I just updated xcode to version 16.0, so I wonder if newer ios images are now stored in some other way/place on my machine.
To summarize I'm using:

xcode: Version 16.0
iPad running OS: 18.0.1
roboVMVersion: 2.3.22

I can deploy a dummy project ok from xcode directly to the same iPad running OS 18.0.1. Inside xcode I also created an iPhone simulator running OS 18.0 and can deploy to that as well. I'm not sure how robovm's launch method is not working but xcode is able to deploy to devices running that OS ok. I suspect robovm is looking at some remnants of my older xcode version and xcode 16.0 is updating images and such in a new way robovm doesn't recognize.
Thanks for any help

I found that this is a known problem, later versions of xcode don't keep the images in the same way as before. Most importantly, the application is deployed to the connected device, it's just that automatically launching it fails.
See:
https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm/issues/755#issuecomment-2112834796
